# Why it's not ok to use interface in this case

Tags: c#, interface

I have the following situation:

```
interface IBaseReader{
   string Header {get; set;}
   string CurrentRow {get; set;}}

class BaseReader: IBaseReader{
   ......}

interface ICustomReader{
   string Header {get; set;}
   string Delimiter {get; set;}}

class CustomReader :BaseReader, ICustomReader{
   ......}
```

In the file proccessing class I am using this ICustomReader to know if derived instance from BaseReader is ICustomReader and if it's than I know that it contains delimiter and I can validate it.

```
IBaseReader _reader;
if(_reader is ICustomReader)
    {
       var items = (_reader as ICustomReader).Header.Split((_reader as ICustomReader).Delimiter);
       //split the current row and header by delimiter and check if it is ok
    }
```

My friends says that its not ok to write such a code because we are checking if instance that is currently represented as IBaseReader is ICustomReaderthat appears in derived class and it's means that base class should know something about derived class. I general We have developed better solution for this. But I am just wondering what exactly it breaks and what will be the right solution in this case, if we just can't move property between classes?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give a proper Title for your question.

Comment: Do you mean `IDerived` instead of `ICustomReader`?

Comment: Thanks for comments I have fixed the example and header

Comment: 'if(IBaseReader _reader is ICustomReader)' this syntax is wrong. Fix it please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with checking for an additional interface to see if a property is available. The problem is that you have two separate interfaces with a `Header` property that don't represent two separate properties. It would be better if `IDerived` inherited `IBaseReader`:

```
interface IDerived : IBaseReader {
   string Delimiter {get; set;}}
```

Or if it was a completely independent interface that is only concerned with the delimiter:

```
interface IHasDelimiter {
   string Delimiter {get; set;}}
```

Then there is no need to cast to the new interface to access the `Header` property because you already have it on the current type of `_reader`:

```
var items = _reader.Header.Split((_reader as ICustomReader).Delimiter);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially coupling the base class `IBaseReader` to a derived class `ICustomReader` when the main reason for creating a hierarchy is to make code reusable.

Now, whenever you want to derive a new interface from `IBaseReader` you are going to have to include `ICustomReader` even if you don't need it.

Comment: You mean "include a referece to `ICustomReader`" don't you? It took me a couple of reads of that sentence to understand what you meant (I first thought that you meant the new interface would need a field of `ICustomReader` or something).

Comment: Mybe I don't understand you correctly but as for me we are using hierarchy to add new futures. In this case dericed class adds some futures but also it contains additional contract(ICustomReader) that allows us to identify it and use some additional logic on it.

Comment: OP said the `ICustomReader`-related code is in "the file processing class" which I assume is separate from `BaseReader`, so there would be no coupling from the base to a derived interface. It's also a conditional check, so it is not necessary -- the code will still function given an instance of `IBaseReader` that does not implement `ICustomReader`.

Answer (score 1):

One major thing that this sort of code will have problems with is fragility.

IF you change `ICustomReader` you should only need to recompile that class and anything that has references to it. This is because only it and anything that uses it explicitly should really know anything about its inner workings (such as its properties).

If you imagine that your `BaseReader` is in one assembly and the `ICustomReader` is in another then any change to the `ICustomReader` (eg it no longer has a delimiter) then it will cause your BaseReader to break for no reason.

If instead you had a virtual method on `BaseReader` called `Validate` or similar then it could be called where you are doing the type specific validation currently. In the base class this method may do nothing if there is no validation to be done. Then in the concrete implementation of `ICustomReader` you can override the Validation to do whatever specific validation you want to do. This way the base class only knows about what it is and what its interface is and what its behaviour is and anything else is worried about by the specific implementations of child classes which know what they do and what needs validating on them.

This has the added benefit that if you add an `ICustomReader2` then you will just need to write that class and not have to go and add extra logic into `BaseReader`. Imagine if you had 50 custom readers how messy that code would be with all manner of if statements checking for specific types. The solution to that messy code would be to refactor your long line of ifs into separate methods, one for each type. Then it is an easy thought of why not put these methods onto the child classes.

The other main reason to do this is to make things simpler to maintain. Somebody new to your code might wonder where the validation for an `ICustomReader` is? Well, its on that class of course. The base class isn't where you would expect it so it will confuse people if it is there.

Good code structure is a fairly large and weighty topic and I've tried to put across some informal arguments that might help you intutively see why that is a bad idea. If you want to google for more info a useful term would be "tightly coupled" and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Disadvantages lists a few of the other disadvantages.

Comment: Base on your comment I assume that you are talking about case when the validation is in base class BUT I have mentioned in the question that the validation logic is in completely different class. So adding new instances of IBaseRedaer don't know anything about validation at all.

Comment: I was thinking about it from that point of view but it can just as easily apply if you were to call `_reader.Validate()` from whatever external class it might be. I'm not sure that the same logic doesn't apply all round. If some readers have a concept of being valid then let all readers have that concept and if it is actually impossible for them to be invalid just do nothing.